# NavigationItem.prompt causing CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following basic storyboard/app:

Navigation Controller > ViewController with Table (code below) > Final ViewController

Whenever I click the navigation back button from the Final ViewController, thus returning to the table view, the following appears in the output.

```
[Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
```

Once I remove the `self.navigationItem.prompt` the error goes away.  Can someone explain how I can remove the error and keep the prompt?  Using XCode 9.4.1.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let data = ["item 1", "item 2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "My Title"
    self.navigationItem.prompt = "My Prompt"

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    c.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return c
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: In Xcode 10.0 Beta2, situation is same.

Comment: In Beta 4, same.

Comment: I think you can ignore this.